# Jmeter variables synchronization

Tags: java, performance, jetty, jmeter

I have problem with Jmeter variables. 
My sampler sending two files per request. I created many files with names like data1, metadata1.

I get those files in such a way:

```
C:\fake_documents\data${__counter(false, data_counter)}
C:\fake_documents\metadata${__counter(false, meta_counter)}
```

This working as well, but sometimes i have problem with counters e.g. data10, metadata11

As the final solution, it's unacceptable

Is a way to synchronize those two counters ?

Comment: Having the same counter variable for both cases is that an option?

Comment: I need something like getter function for this counter. For first file getCounter(), for second getAndIncrement().

Comment: Just remove the second counter function and use ${data_counter} instead. So you will have the same value

Comment: I found information, multiple __counter function calls in the same iteration won't increment the value further. But __counter(false, counter) sometimes gave different results. @AndreyPohilko solution working perfect.

Answer (score 0):

[__counter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function allows you to export the value to a variable you can later use, it's the second parameter of the function

So you would just do:

> C:\fake_documents\data${__counter(false, data_counter)}
>
> C:\fake_documents\metadata${data_counter}